# Avoid executable text files in SVN

Tags: windows, svn

In a repository of ours, users from different OS have access. Some of them, usually the Windows users, check in all kinds of files as *executable*, which is a pain for the Unix users.

I consider it a design flaw in Subversion that the sheer existence or non-existence of `svn:executable` on a file decides about the executable bit instead of differentiating between ‘forgot to set it’ and ‘it really is not executable’.

Anyway, is there a way to solve this technically, not socially? A commit-hook perhaps, or a configuration entry for wide-spread Windows subversion clients (ideally Eclipse)?

Comment: How is this any more of a flaw that e.g. Unix file permission flags?

Comment: Also, what tool is causing text files to be committed with properties set like that?  That just sounds broken.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it is more broken because Unix file permissions stay on Unix, but SVN file permissions are spanning systems and have to handle clients that are not on Unix systems. The tool that set the executable bit was most probably Ecplipse with Subclipse (don’t know whether JavaHL or SVNKit).

Comment: This will be remedied to some extent in http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config . However the server or client can't unambiguously know in all cases whether a file should be executable or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pre-commit hook to check the filename and then modify the executable flag based on the file extensions:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks

Answer (score 0):

Use A Precommit hook.
Inside a precommit hook, using SVNLook, get the filenames, cut the extension part and based on the types of extensions you want to restrict, give the message to user for diabled files.

Answer (score 0):

> I consider it a design flaw in Subversion that the sheer existence or non-existence of svn:executable on a file decides about the executable bit instead of differentiating between ‘forgot to set it’ and ‘it really is not executable’.

In Windows, file suffixes determine executability or not. Putting `svn:executable` on a file doesn't make any difference in Windows, and I can't understand why your Windows users are doing this for Batch files. It's only messing with Unix people's minds.

The problem is that Unix uses file permissions in determining file executability. An executable file could be called anything, and there's no easy way to determine it except that a file that's executable has this execute permission bit set.

Subversion uses the `svn:executable` property solely to determine whether or not to set this bit when the file is checked out. On Windows, it doesn't matter if `foo.bat` has this bit set or not. It's executable. On Unix, setting `svn:executable` simply makes the permissions on `foo` to be `rwxr-xr-x` instead of `rw-r--r--`.

Even stranger, you make it sound like Subversion is forcing Unix users to execute non-executable files. As far as I'm concerned, all files in the repository can have `svn:executable` on them. I am not going to execute programs willy-nilly even if they can be run unless I know what that program is doing.

No, the real issue between Windows and Unix is file suffixes. That's where the real pain is. If I create a shell script on Windows, even if I set `svn:executable` on that file, it won't execute on Unix because Windows put on those `CRLF` line endings, and Unix will choke on those.

I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that can be used to ensure that properties are set on files. I use this to force users to put `svn:eol-style` = `LF` on shell scripts and Makefiles, or to set `svn:eol-style` = `CRLF` on Windows batch script. You can even use it to force users to set `svn:executable` on files. For example, we make sure that all files in the `bin` directory or that end in `*.sh` have this bit set. To us, this bit not being set when it should be is the problem. Not, that this bit is set, and it shouldn't be.

However, there's nothing in this hook that says *Don't set this property*. But, if that's important to you, you're free to take this pre-commit hook and modify it.